# Difference between IntelliType and IntelliType Pro

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, keyboard, intellitype

When downloading drivers for my keyboard (a Microsoft Natural Wireless Ergonomic Keyboard 7000), Microsoft  [offers](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/natural-ergonomic-desktop-7000/WTA-00001#support) me, among other options, these two:

- IntelliType 8.15
- IntelliType Pro 6.31

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that IntelliType 8.15 is actually IntelliType **Pro** 8.15. I found these links:

Intellitype
x64:
http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/A/7/AA7AB701-B35D-4EA7-A02A-BAAD536EA8CF/ITPx64_1033_8.15.406.0.exe
x86:
http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/A/7/AA7AB701-B35D-4EA7-A02A-BAAD536EA8CF/ITPx86_1033_8.15.406.0.exe

So if you look at the file name, it starts with **ITP** which stands for **IntelliType Pro**. They both end with 8.15.xxx.x which is the same version number you gave in your question.

So the only difference between them is the version number. I'd go for the 8.15.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that there's a difference between the "Pro" and non "Pro" versions other than they dropped that part of the name.

Which version you should use depends on the OS and whether or not you're 64bit.  I found this screen is most helpful in choosing which you should use based on your setup.

http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/d/natural-wireless-ergonomic-keyboard-7000